# Updating Particular field in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to update the field data only ,but my code it adding an object each time i am calling update api.I have gone through many sites and found out updateOne is the method but couldnt end up undersatnding how to implement here.I am quite new to node so any help would be appreciated.

```js
const update=(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req);
  
    models.detailsSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.vehicleId,req.body.data,{new:true}).then((msg,err)=>{  

        if(err) 
         res.status(400).json({err})
       res.status(200).json({
           "resCode":"0000",
           "resStatus":"Success",
           "resMsg":msg
       })  
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Mongoose connected to a MongoDB instance? If that's the case, `Schema.findByIdAndUpdate` works on the primary key or ObjectId of the record you're trying to update. To make this code work, if my assumptions are correct, change to this:

```js
models.detailsSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body.data, { new:true })
```

Of course, you're going to want to put in some check to make sure `_id` is defined if this is a create/update route.